# GAE - Wordpress Admin Login Through Custom Domain?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, google-app-engine, ssl

I'm  trying to set up a Wordpress Multisite network on Google App Engine. I have the install up and running, and am mapping custom domains for each site with the help of [this plugin.](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) I'm using Wordpress 4.0.

The domain mapping works, in that when I navigate to the custom domain it pulls up the corresponding site, but when I try to access any admin pages from the custom domain, I get an SSL error. I gather that this is due to Google's not allowing custom domains to access GAE apps via SSL, and so I've been trying to fix this by redirecting all requests of the form `mycustomdomain.com/wp-admin/(.+)` to `myapp.appspot.com/wp-admin/\1`.

My rationale for trying this is that `myapp.appspot.com/subsite/wp-admin/` works just fine, but `mycustomdomain/wp-admin` does not, despite the two pointing to the same location.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure out how to do this redirection properly. I've tried adding redirect rules to the `.htaccess` file with no success. I've also tried messing with `app.yaml` handlers, but this, too, yielded no results.

Also worth noting is that I attempted to force all requests to go through http (as a hackish, temporary workaround) via [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/force-non-ssl/) to no avail.

I'm new to working with servers, and any help would be much appreciated. I'm not even sure that redirection is the right solution, so I welcome any other suggestions. I can supply pertinent code if needed. Thanks.

**EDIT:** I could go through Google's custom domain registration process via Google Apps and get an SSL certificate that way, but my app will eventually be used by a large number of independent sites that I don't control, so that solution won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to achieve something similar on a regular server and not on GAE, so I'm not sure this will apply to you...

Isn't the 4th option of the Domain Mapping what you're looking for? In the WP network administration, go to Settings > Domain Mapping, then you can tick/untick the 4th option :

```
4. Redirect administration pages to site's original domain (remote login disabled if this redirect is disabled)
```

This will allow you to use a custom domain to access a site and its wp-admin interface, allowing SSL certificates to validate since the domain stays the same.